# how to do swipe action in android

Tags: android, swipe

in my app when an activity is opened i am have a edit boxes to be filled.  When the user fills the edit box, a default music will be played in background. If the user wants to select another song, he can select a song from a list view which shows all the song stored in sd card.

Now i want to show the list view when the user swipe's the screen to left.

I have already written the code for my edit boxes and list of songs separately and they are working good. Now i want to swipe between those activities.

please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Also note that you'll probably want to swipe between Views, not Activities

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a project that uses swipe actions a lot.

It is open-source, feel free to copy-paste the code:
https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android

Especially this class:
https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/blob/dbbf3ea6549e82dee9e3c0df39bb5c3f74d3e189/AnkiDroid/src/main/java/com/ichi2/anki/AbstractFlashcardViewer.java